# How do you get tasks from all lists using the Google Tasks API?

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I am currently using the Tasks API Java client in my Android app in this way:

```
List<Task> tasks = client.tasks()
    .list("@default")
    .setFields("items(title,notes,status,due)")
    .execute()
    .getItems();
```

But this only returns the tasks from the "Default" task list. Is there a way to get the tasks from all task lists, without having to get the lists from `client.tasklists()` and iterate through them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No**.

As the documentation specifies, the `list` action "Returns all tasks in the *specified* task list".

The "restful" style is that all resources belong to a collection. As such, using `list` for Tasks requires acting it on a TaskList. As you noted, it's very simple to list all TaskLists, then list all Tasks from each TaskList and collect them in a list.  Note that one might even argue that in many circumstances, a Task is meaningless when separated from the context of the list it was created in.

You can see the full [Api Reference for Tasks API here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/).

Comment: This restful style is not very useful. A TaskList can be changed any time by the user. If you have a taskID and do not know the new TaskList-ID then there is no fast way of searching for the task. Going through all the tasklists and listing all the tasks is just ridiculously time-consuming.